# Use translation for submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, i18n-gem

I don't want to use the default

```
<%= f.submit %>
```

and have created a helper function for it, which also embeds an icon.  The helper function expects a label to put on the newly created button.

I'm calling it like this:

```
<%= submit_button("icon-plus", I18n.translate("helpers.submit.create")) %>
```

But now on this text appears on the button:

*%{model} toevoegen*

Instead of:

*Product type toevoegen*

If I use the normal submit button then the correct text appears so my yml files are correct.  How can I get the correct text to use in the helper?

Helper code:

```
def submit_button(icon, label)
  link_to "javascript:void(0)", :class => 'btn btn-primary', :onclick => "$(this).closest('form').submit()" do
  raw('<div class="') + icon + raw(' icon-white"> ') + label +raw('</div>')
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you provide the helper code? I suspect you need to replace `%{model}` with `#{model}`.

Comment: Added helper code.  I already tried replacing the code to #{model} but that doesn't work, and even breaks the caption on the normal submits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [I18n guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations) says, the `translate` function interpolates variables passed in the `%{}` brackets using its second argument (a hash).

In your case you need to tell it the `model` by doing this:

```
I18n.t("helpers.submit.create", model: "Product type")
```

If you want a generic option that would work for any model, you can see how Rails itself does it by looking at the source [on GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.11/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1421-L1425) - it's something like

```
I18n.t("helpers.submit.create", model: f.object.class.model_name.human)
```

As an aside, you don't need to (and probably shouldn't) use `raw` there. What you are trying to achieve could easily be done with the built-in helpers:

```
link_to ... do
  content_tag :div, label, class: "#{icon} icon-white"
end
```

Comment: What a great answer!!!  Thanks, working completely.  Gonna try to replace the first part as well now to make it more generic.

Comment: Make this:
  def create_or_update(object)
    "helpers.submit." + (object ? (object.persisted? ? :update : :create) : :submit).to_s
  end

So now I can call create_or_update(f.object) and it will work for updates too.